# while loop continues even if the condition is not satisfied anymore

Tags: java

```
public class SumOfTwoNum {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int med = numbers.length/2;
        if (numbers[med] > target) {
            twoSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers,0,med), target);
        }
        int remainNum;
        int index1 = -1;
        int index2 = -1;
        while (index1 == -1 && index2 == -1) {
            remainNum = target-numbers[med];
            if (remainNum > numbers[med]) {
                index2 = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers,med,numbers.length,remainNum);
                index1 = med;
            } else {
                index1 = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers,0,med,remainNum);
                index2 = med;
            }
            //here I get index1=0 and index2=1, but the loop doesn't stop
            med --;

        }
        return new int[] {index1, index2};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumOfTwoNum s = new SumOfTwoNum();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.twoSum(new int[] {2,7,11,15},9)));
        //what I hope to get here is {0,1}, but it returns {-1,2}
    }
}
```

I want to get the index of two numbers which adds up to the target
but when it goes into the loop, even if both index1 and index2 are not -1, it still keeps looping

Comment: you could just create a boolean flag for this? basically `boolean finished = false` and on your while `while(!finished)` then at the bottom of the while block or wherever you deem it better add `finished = index1 != -1 && index2 != -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that after the recursive call, your function doesn't returns, so the loop executes twice. That's why it seems that the loop is executing even when the conditions becomes false.

You need to return the result of the recursive call.

```
if (numbers[med] > target) {
     return twoSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers,0,med), target);
}
```